# using node.js async series, but doesn't work

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I want to use async to make node.js work something in order, first query two rates from mongodb,then use these rates to compute two new rate:

```
async.series([
    function(callback){
        db.collection('heros',function(err,collection){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
            if(!err){
                console.log("2 collection fetched!");
                collection.findOne({'id':win},function(err,result){
                    if (err) throw err;
                    rate1=result.rate;
                    console.log("win-rate:"+rate1);
                });
                collection.findOne({'id':lose},function(err,result){
                    if (err) throw err;
                    rate2=result.rate;
                    console.log("lose-rate:"+rate2);
                });         
            }
        });
        callback(null);

    }, function(callback){   
        var Ea= 1/(1+Math.pow(10,(rate2-rate1)/400));
        var Eb= 1/(1+Math.pow(10,(rate1-rate2)/400));
        var ra= rate1+16*(1-Ea);
        var rb= rate2+16*(0-Eb);
        console.log("ra:"+ra);
        console.log("rb:"+rb);
        callback(null);
    },
        function(callback){   
    db.collection('heros',function(err,collection){
        if(!err){
        collection.update({'id':win},{$set:    {rate:ra}},function(err,result){
          if(err) throw err;
          if(!err){
            console.log("update successful");
          }
          });
          collection.update({'id':lose},{$set:{rate:rb}},function(err,result){
          if(err) throw err;
          if(!err){
            console.log("update successful");
        }
        });

            }

    });
    callback(null);
}
]);
```

but when I run it, it shows error messages:

> ReferenceError: ra is not defined

it seems that nodejs jumps to computing or updating without waiting for the query complete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're declaring the variables like `ra` inside of a function block, so they're scoped to that function and unavailable elsewhere. You'd need to put them somewhere more accessible. For example, you could put them in a global variable:

```
var ra;

async.series([ ... ]);
```

Further, when you use series, you should call the `callback` function only when all of the work for that step has completed.

For example, one task should look like this:

```
db.collection('heros',function(err,collection){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);  // log the error
            callback(err);     // call the async call back with the error
            return;            // stop 
        }
        console.log("2 collection fetched!");
        collection.findOne({'id':win},function(err,result){
            if (err) { callback(err); return; } // again, handle error
            rate1 = result.rate;                // grab results
            console.log("win-rate:"+rate1);     // log
            callback(null, rate1);              // now indicate complete by calling
        });
    });
```

As you've got multiple async function calls within a single task, you may want to split them to multiple tasks or consider using the `parallel` function as well. You could even use `parallel` within one of the other tasks in the `series` call to handle the case where you have two `findOne` calls that need to be made.